# HC-05 Bluetooth module not turning on with 3.3V voltage regulator with enable control

Tags: voltage-regulator, bluetooth, hc-05

I am trying use the following circuit for HC-05 power supply on/off control but the HC-05 module is not turning on after the enable signal is set to high.

While testing the HC-05 on/off operation, BLUETOOTH_TX, BLUETOOTH_RX and BLUETOOTH_KEY signal are disconnected from the main circuit.

I have tried MIC5205-3.3YM5, MIC5219-3.3YM5 and RT9193-33GB but no success.

Just to check what's happening with circuit I connected the digital scope's ground to circuit ground and all of a sudden circuit started working.

As soon as I removed digital scope's ground from the circuit ground, the  circuit stopped working.

I am not able to figure out what's wrong with the circuit.

[image]

Comment: please do not put a question mark on the end of a statement ... it does not make it into a question ... at best it asks about your ability, not about the circuit

Comment: What have you tested? Did you test that the circuit is getting 3.3V? Did you test all grounds are connected? Did you check in the datasheet if the reset pin can be left unconnected?